# Can we leverage tag info usage for Code Review?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I just checked the [tag info](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) for [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), which is basically a copy of the C++ tag info from Stack Overflow.

I though that was a bit of a waste. Have we had any thoughts about using this specifically for Code Review?

Comment: [Related answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1648/9357)

Answer (score 11):

We could put common issues and deviations from standard idioms.

That way we don't have to mention the same thing every time. We could have a boilerplate that we add to the top of new questions with crosses that apply to normal failures and an expansive section on the tag info section on what should be done and why.

Comment: Interesting idea. I could see us doing this for some other tags as well. ++

Comment: @RubberDuck: I was definitely thinking about other tags than C++. We have so few repeat situations that it would never really apply :-)

Comment: You mean I shouldn't include stdio? =;)- Seriously though, right now I'm thinking of adding a section to VBA about not using Activate/Select.